# Converting from abstract data type to generic type

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I am trying to figure out how to convert from an abstract templated class to a generic data type as seen below. Specifically, `A::m_data` will hold class `B<T>` as a data type. Eventually I want to be able to convert `A::m_data` to whatever data type `B::m_data` is holding. In this case, to an integer.

Currently, I get the error on line 28:

> binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

```cpp
template <typename T>
class B;

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    T m_data;

    operator A<B<T>>()
    {
        return T(m_data);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
public:
    T m_data;
};

int main()
{
    A <B<int>> foo;
    B<int> bar;
    bar.m_data = 10;

    foo.m_data = bar.m_data;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because `foo.m_data` is a `B<int>` and `bar.m_data` is an `int`, and you have not defined an `operator=` for `B` that takes a `T` as input, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class B
{
public:
    T m_data;

    B& operator=(const T &value) {
        m_data = value;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/GbTmGJ)

It is not really clear what your `A::operator()` is trying to return.  But since you say you want `A::m_data` to eventually be the same type as `B::m_data`, you can use [`decltype()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) for that, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    using data_type = decltype(T::m_data);

    data_type m_data;

    operator data_type()
    {
        return m_data;
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/o4fWpg)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much really appreciate it!